# Certain applications' graphics are painfully slow in lubuntu 15

Tags: linux, drivers, graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, lubuntu

I have an oldish GeForce 6200 EVGA PCI card 512Mb DDR2, with the (updated) Nvidia driver 304.128 installed on Lubuntu 15.1.

CSS and LXDE transitions are painfully slow, making me think they're not hardware accelerated at all. However, the benchmark GPU scores seem OK; 17s for FPU raytracing, 1.3 for FPU FFT. The driver is also managing two 1024*1280 screens; it's just all the animated transitions that are causing problems. Any ideas what's going on?

Edit: still haven't cracked this. `glxgears` is showing 60fps, so the GPU is definitely capable of handling window transitions etc. Gnumeric is completely unusable. It takes about 1500ms to enter data into an individual cell, and the window can't be resized without artifacts. Libreoffice calc renders fine. I'm really baffled.

Comment: It sounds like that distribution you attempting to use simply is to resource intensive for your decade old GeForce 6200.

Comment: Doesn't Lubuntu purposely not accelerate to keep it simpler? I believe this is true

Comment: LXDE is about as lightweight a window manager as it gets. I don't know about whether LXDE's transitions make use of GPUs (I don't have sufficient graphics programming experience), but if it's CPU only it shouldn't be a bottleneck (AMD FX 6300). And CSS transitions (webkit and gecko) are also super slow. I pointed out, the FPU scores aren't *that* bad...